# How to download .xslx File from server using EPPlus and MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, download, epplus

I have an Excel file generated on the server by using EPPlus the file is correctly made and using a window.location works fine on the local machine but does nothing when its deployed to a server. I'm trying to return a FileStreamResult back through the MVC controller but i don't think it's working. i'm using an ajax call to access the controller method but it fails to enter .done when the method is run through.

i have been looking at [ASP.NET MVC EPPlus Download Excel File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18728995/asp-net-mvc-epplus-download-excel-file) for my C# reference.

Script

```
 function exportToExcel() {
    var batchName = $("#batchDateSelect option:selected").text();
    var bID = $("#batchDateSelect").val();
    var params = {
        BatchID: bID,
        BatchName: batchName
    };
    $.post(path + "Export/ExportToExcel", params)
    .done(function (Data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        var fileName = "";

        ////window.location = path + "ExportFiles/"+fileName;
    });

}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult ExportToExcel(int BatchID,string BatchName)
{

    FileStreamResult FSR = DataAccess.ExportUtility.CreateExcelFile(BatchID, BatchName);

    return FSR;

}
```

EPPlus Method

```
public static FileStreamResult CreateExcelFile(int batchid,string batchName)
    {

        string fileName = batchName + " Reason_Code_Export.xlsx";
        var serverPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/ExportFiles/");
        DirectoryInfo outputDir = new DirectoryInfo(serverPath);

        FileInfo newfile = new FileInfo(outputDir.FullName + fileName);
        if (newfile.Exists)
        {
            newfile.Delete();
            newfile = new FileInfo(outputDir.FullName + fileName);
        }
        Dictionary<string,int> MAData = PolicyDataAccess.GetMatchActionData(batchid);
        MemoryStream MS = new MemoryStream();
        using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(newfile))
        {
            ..........
            ........

            package.SaveAs(MS);
        }
        MS.Position = 0;
        var contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

        FileStreamResult FSR = new FileStreamResult(MS, contentType);
        FSR.FileDownloadName = fileName;



        return FSR;
    }
```

What is the easiest way to Get that file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm late to this question but may be it will be helpful for others.

After you setup the excel sheet then **without saving or adding it to the MemoryStream**, just make array of bytes as **packge.GetAsByteArray()** and from your action return it **as a File instead of FileStreamResult**.

```
var FileBytesArray = packge.GetAsByteArray();
return File(FileBytesArray, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", filename + ".xlsx");
```

Answer (score 1):

EPPLUS has given me some real headaches. 
 And I'm not so familiar with MVC, but i assume you want to do something along the lines of writing directly to the output response.  In that case, I use something like what's below.
  and I see i left in the comments that the memory stream write works as well.  that's closer to what you are asking to do but i do not currently use it in my code. so buyer beware.
  .cheers.

```
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

        Response.AddHeader( "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=ProposalRequest-" + fileName + ".xslx" );
        Response.BinaryWrite( pck.GetAsByteArray() );
        // myMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream); //works too
        Response.Flush();
        Response.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped with a problem related to "corrupted" files while editing a template with epplus

Answer (score -1):

The answer that DougY has post probably works fine, however i did find a solution before he posted.

I won't mark this as answered because i'm sure there is a better way, if anyone wants to post or comment on what's the best way to do it ill mark an answer then.

thanks for the response DougY

The 2 methods of the controller could probably be combined, but this is just how it ended up.

Controller

```
public static string ContentType { get; set; }
public static string FilePath { get; set; }
public static string FileName { get; set; }
public static byte[] Bytes { get; set; }

public void ExportToExcel(int BatchID,string BatchName)//is called first to set the variables
    {
        string contentType;
        byte[] bytes;
        string ret = DataAccess.ExportUtility.CreateExcelFile(BatchID, BatchName,out contentType, out bytes);
        ContentType = contentType;
        Bytes = bytes;

        FileName = ret[1];




    }
    public ActionResult DownloadExcelFile()//is then called to download the file
    {

        return File(Bytes, ContentType, FileName);

    }
```

ExportUtility class

```
public static string[] CreateExcelFile(int batchid,string batchName,out string ContentType, out byte[] Bytes)
    {

        string fileName = batchName + " Reason_Code_Export.xlsx";

        var serverPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/ExportFiles/");
        DirectoryInfo outputDir = new DirectoryInfo(serverPath);
        byte[] bytes;
        FileInfo newfile = new FileInfo(outputDir.FullName + fileName);
        if (newfile.Exists)
        {
            newfile.Delete();
            newfile = new FileInfo(outputDir.FullName + fileName);
        }
        Dictionary<string,int> MAData = PolicyDataAccess.GetMatchActionData(batchid);
        MemoryStream MS = new MemoryStream();
        ExcelPackage package;
        using (package = new ExcelPackage(newfile))
        {
            ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(batchName);

            worksheet.Cells["A1"].Value = batchName + " Reason_Code_Export";
            worksheet.Cells["A1"].Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;
            worksheet.Cells["A1:B1"].Merge = true;
            worksheet.Cells["A1:B1"].Style.Font.Bold = true;

            worksheet.Cells["A2"].Value = "Reason Code";
            worksheet.Cells["B2"].Value = "Number of Reason Codes Selected";
            worksheet.Cells["A2:B2"].Style.Font.Bold = true;
            int row = 3;
            int col = 1;
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string,int> MA in MAData)
            {
                worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value = MA.Key;
                worksheet.Cells[row, col + 1].Value = MA.Value;
                row++;

            }
            worksheet.Column(1).Width = 34.29;
            worksheet.Column(2).Width = 34.29;

            package.Workbook.Properties.Title = batchName + " Reason_Code_Export";
            package.Workbook.Properties.Author = "Intranet Application: Unclaimed Properties";
            package.Workbook.Properties.Company = "Assurity Life 2013";
            Bytes = package.GetAsByteArray();
            //package.SaveAs(newfile);//MS);

        }
        MS.Position = 0;
        var rl = serverPath + fileName;
        var contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        ContentType = contentType;
        FileStreamResult FSR = new FileStreamResult(MS, contentType);
        FSR.FileDownloadName = fileName;
        string[] ret = new string[2];
        ret[0] = serverPath;
        ret[1] = fileName;


        return ret;
    }
```