# Does anybody know how to get xlsx support for SQL Server 2008 R2 Reporting Services without upgrading to SQL Server 2012 or 3rd party tools?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008-r2

Does anybody know how to get **export to XLSX** support for SQL Server 2008 R2 Reporting Services without upgrading to SQL Server 2012 or using any 3rd party tools?

[image: export button in report server]

Comment: we had a similar situation..but ended up upgrading to 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from developing your own render?  Nope.  I haven't been able to find ANY information on that by the way.

Apart from going to SQL Server 2012 (a [3rd party renderer](http://www.officewriter.com/officewriter-for-sql-server-reporting-services.aspx) may be more cost effective) you could develop your own ASP.Net app while using [EPPlus](http://www.codeplex.com/epplus) that would link from the report.  This [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18728995/asp-net-mvc-epplus-download-excel-file) may help start you off with the code.

Comment: This [FAQ](http://windowsitpro.com/sql-server-2012/top-ten-sql-server-2012-faqs) might help when considering a 2012 upgrade - but remember CALs as well!  There's now a "Business Intelligence" edition of SQL Server which you could run your SSIS reports from - this isn't licensed per core.