# Export to Excel fails on some machines

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel

We are developing a Web application and some of our query results need to be Exported to Excel. We are using the following C# code to Export :

```
System.Web.HttpContext ctx = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
CurrentPackingListModel.Voyage.ShipmentDataContext = ShipmentDataContext;
ctx.Response.Clear();
string filename = "ApprovalForm.xls";
ctx.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename);
ctx.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
ctx.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8");
ctx.Response.Charset = "UTF-8";
return View("../Packing/_ExportApprovalForm", CurrentPackingListModel);
```

The partial View I am returning to result is as follows :

```
<body id="body" onload="window.print();">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="table-header" colspan="8">
                    <div style="width: 100%">
                        <div class="lleft">
                            @* <img id="imgLogo" src="~/Images/myLogo.png" />*@
                        </div>
                        <div class="baslik">Approval Packing List Form</div>
                        <div style="float: right;">@DateTime.Now.ToString("MM.dd.yyyy")</div>
                    </div>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="line-header">@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.ID)</td>
                <td>: @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ID)@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.ID)</td>

                <td class="line-header" style="width: 165px;">@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.Voyage.StartDate)</td>
                <td>: @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Voyage.StartDate)</td>

                <td class="line-header">@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.Voyage.VesselID)</td>
                <td>: @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Voyage.VesselText)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="line-header">@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.Voyage.Id)</td>
                <td>: @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Voyage.Id)</td>

                <td class="line-header" style="width: 165px;">@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.Voyage.EndDate)</td>
                <td>: @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Voyage.EndDate)</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="6">
                    <hr />
                </td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>

    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="line-header" style="width: 160px;">Approve Personel</td>
            <td style="border: solid 1px; width: 180px;"></td>
            <td class="line-header">Discharge Port</td>
            <td style="border: solid 1px; width: 180px;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="line-header">Approve Date</td>
            <td style="border: solid 1px;"></td>
            <td class="line-header">Terminal</td>
            <td style="border: solid 1px;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="line-header">Signiture</td>
            <td style="border: solid 1px;"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    @if (Request.QueryString["type"] == "HRC" && Model.HrcListPrint != null)
    {
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="10" style="height: 20px;">
                    <hr />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: center; width: 210mm; font-weight: bold;" colspan="11">HRC LIST
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
        <table class="display dataTable no-footer">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Customer Name</th>
                    <th>Customer PO No</th>
                    <th>Ord. ITem No</th>
                    <th>CM No</th>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th>Size (T x W inch)</th>
                    <th>Thickness Tolerance</th>
                    <th>Qty (tons)</th>
                    <th>Coil Weight (Lbs)</th>
                    <th>Destination Port</th>
                    <th>Barcode</th>
                    <th>Heat No</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (MedTrade.Apollo.Shared.Models.Shipment.PackingListDetailModel item in Model.HrcListPrint)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@item.CustomerName</td>
                        <td>@item.CustomerPurchaseOrderNumber</td>
                        <td>@String.Format("'{0}'", item.OrderItemText)</td>
                        <td>@item.CMNO</td>
                        <td>@item.ProductStandartName</td>
                        <td>@item.ProductProperty</td>
                        <td>@item.ThicknessToleranceType</td>
                        <td>@((item.Quantity / 1000).ToString("N3"))</td>
                        <td>@item.CoilWeight.ToString("N0")</td>
                        <td>@item.DischargePortTanim</td>
                        <td>@item.BarcodeNo</td>
                        <td>@item.HeatNo</td>
                        <td>@item.StatusText</td>
                    </tr>    
                }

            </tbody>
        </table>
    }

    @if (Request.QueryString["type"] == "Rebar" && Model.RebarListPrint != null)
    {
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="10" style="height: 20px;">
                    <hr />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: center; width: 210mm; font-weight: bold;" colspan="10">REBAR LIST
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>

        <table class="display dataTable no-footer">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Customer Name</th>
                    <th>Customer PO No</th>
                    <th>Ord. ITem No</th>
                    <th>CM No</th>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th>Size (D x L inch)</th>
                    @if (Model.SearchCriteria.ViewType == ViewType.Group)
                    {
                        <th>Qty (tons) / # of bundles</th>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <th>Quantity (Tons)</th>
                    }
                    <th>Bundle Weight (Lbs)</th>
                    <th>Destination Port</th>
                    @if (Model.SearchCriteria.ViewType == ViewType.Detail)
                    {
                        <th>Barcode</th>
                    }
                    <th>Heat No</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (MedTrade.Apollo.Shared.Models.Shipment.PackingListDetailModel item in Model.RebarListPrint)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@item.CustomerName</td>
                        <td>@item.CustomerPurchaseOrderNumber</td>
                        <td>@String.Format("'{0}'", item.OrderItemText)</td>
                        <td>@item.CMNO</td>
                        <td>@item.ProductStandartName</td>
                        <td>@item.ProductProperty</td>
                        @if (Model.SearchCriteria.ViewType == ViewType.Group)
                        {
                            <td>@((item.Quantity / 1000).ToString("N3")) / @item.Count</td>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <td>@((item.Quantity / 1000).ToString("N3"))</td>
                        }
                        <td>@item.BundleWeight.ToString("N0")</td>
                        <td>@item.DischargePortTanim</td>
                        @if (Model.SearchCriteria.ViewType == ViewType.Detail)
                        {
                            <td>@item.BarcodeNo</td>
                        }
                        <td>@item.HeatNo</td>
                        <td>@item.StatusText</td>
                    </tr>    
                }

            </tbody>
        </table>        
    }

</body>
```

But export to Excel works on some machines, but not others. This started to happen only recently.

Is there a possible solution to fix this without re-writing the whole Exporting functionality?

Comment: This isn't generating an Excel file, it fakes it by generating an HTML table and using a misleading extension and content-type. I admit, I never saw *this* kind of hack thoug - use the View to generate the HTML table and change the response headers. Use a library like EPPlus to generate a *real* Excel file. It's easier, faster and results in a much smaller download.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Using EPPlus is an option but we have to re-write all export to Excel functionality for all pages, which is an option I am trying to avoid. I am trying to find a quicker way to solve, if possible.

Comment: You don't have any Excel support at the moment, you are generating HTML tables and hope Excel can decipher them. EPPlus *is* the quickest option. All you need is `worksheet.LoadFromCollection(CurrentPackingListModel.Items);` to generate a sheet from a list of items. After that, return a FileResult with the sheet

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18728995/asp-net-mvc-epplus-download-excel-file) to see how to generate the sheet in a memory stream and send it, without even requiring a View.

Comment: After seeing the HTML view, I double down on unfixable. The view actually contains logic that controls which tables get generated, something that should be done by the controller. Conditionals and formatting code appear inside the cells themselves. Calling `ToString()` on decimals means that the browser's locale will be used to generate text that may or may not be parsed the same

Answer (score 2):

Apologies this is not an answer but i am unable to comment as i have low rep.

IS excel installed on the machines it is not working on? From my memory excel must be installed for you to export. I have used [Epplus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) to get around this in the past.

Are you able to add some exception handling and logging around this issued so you can get more details from the error? Even if you just write it to a txt file on the machine.

Sorry i dont have any actual answers.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Yes Excel 2013 is installed on all machines. Using EPPlus is an option but we have to re-write all export to Excel functionality for all pages, which is an option I am trying to avoid. We are catching error, but the code does not throw any Exception. I can export an Excel file but it rather does not open or open as blank.

Comment: @user3021830 you *don't* have any Excel support at the moment, you are using a hack to generate HTML tables. This is unfixable. That's because Excel *imports* the HTML file you generate using each machine's default locale settings. You have *no* control over that process. Eg, in France, Germany, Greece, the decimal separator is `,`. Any CSV/HTML table loaded in Excel in these countries will display the wrong numeric values. A real XLSX file won't have any problem though

Comment: @user3021830 you didn't post the code that actually generates the HTML table (ie your View). It could be that the content can't be imported at all, eg, more than one tables, nested tables, or any other thing that would prevent importing

Comment: I also addded my View to the question. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @user3021830 unfixable^2 due to conditionals and locale-specific decimal to string conversions. If you don't specify the invariant culture in `ToString()` or `String.Format` the request's locale is used, which is affected by the browser's locale. Even if one user can open the file, another user may have trouble

Answer (score -1):

May below code will be helpful for you:

```
public void ExportToExcel()
{
  DataGrid dgGrid = new DataGrid();
  dgGrid.DataSource = /*Give your data source here*/;

  dgGrid.DataBind();
  System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
  System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
  System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",    string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "Data Report.xls"));
  System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
  System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "";
  System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
  HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
  dgGrid.RenderControl(htw);
  System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
  System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
  System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```

Comment: This isn't generating an Excel file, it fakes it by generating an HTML table and using a misleading extension

Comment: In fact, the OP's code does exactly the same - the view renders a table and the headers are changed to make the browser think this is an Excel file